# Kazam 1.5.4 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, kazam

There is a repository (ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam) for the latest Kazam, but that one, when I add it, it says it had no Release file and therefore cant be used.

Now, how do I install the latest Kazam with webcam support on my Ubuntu 19.04?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party repositories, and you should check for support yourself, as they are supported by the owner, but Ubuntu. 
 Looking at https://launchpad.net/~sylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/kazam/+packages I see support stopped at 18.04, so you need to contact the owner, or find another source for the software you like.  Note the owner states *This PPA currently publishes packages for Bionic, Artful, Zesty, Yakkety, and Xenial*

Comment: Thank you! I sadly can't find any other PPA though.

Comment: You can trick/force your system to use the 'bionic' release for the PPA, but this involves doing homework to ensure you aren't creating problems or dependency-hell for yourself further down the road (eg. when you next need to release-upgrade to 19.10 etc). People who use this approach are probably more likely to *nuke&install* for each release instead of the intended release-upgrade path to avoid some pitfalls (*I'm intentionally being vague as if you can't understand the approach I'm talking about, you probably don't have the skill to detect potential pitfalls before you hit them*)